# SQL - Join 2 tables on a substring of metadata

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, one contains a metadata field like the following:

```
<ACTIONMETA>
   <OBJECTGUID1>BC9E38A1-5A60-4648-A121-9F3E48B828F7</OBJECTGUID1>
   <OBJECTGUID2>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</OBJECTGUID2>
</ACTIONMETA>
```

The other table has a field that matches the substring between the .

I want to join these 2 tables together.  Here is my code:

```
select ca.Metadata, * from [dbo].[CustomAction] ca
inner join [dbo].[CustomScript] cs on 
cs.CustomScriptGUID=substring(ca.Metadata, 
charindex('1>',ca.Metadata)+2,charindex('</',ca.Metadata)-
charindex('1>',ca.Metadata)-2)
```

This always gives me an error.  I also tried the following:

```
select ca.Metadata, substring(ca.Metadata, 
charindex('1>',ca.Metadata)+2,charindex('</',ca.Metadata)-
charindex('1>',ca.Metadata)-2) as ca.CustomScriptGUID, 
from [dbo].[CustomAction] ca
inner join [dbo].[CustomScript] cs on 
cs.CustomScriptGUID=ca.CustomScriptGUID
```

Again, always get an error.  Is there a way to join these on this type of substring?

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: I think you mean: `select ca.Metadata, cs.* from`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option, and perhaps a little cleaner

**If metadata has a datatype of XML**

```
Select ca.Metadata , * 
 From [dbo].[CustomAction] ca
 Join [dbo].[CustomScript] cs 
   on cs.CustomScriptGUID = ca.metadata.value('ACTIONMETA[1]/OBJECTGUID1[1]','varchar(max)')
```

**If metadata is a string**

```
Select ca.Metadata , * 
 From [dbo].[CustomAction] ca
 Join [dbo].[CustomScript] cs 
   on cs.CustomScriptGUID = cast(ca.metadata as xml).value('ACTIONMETA[1]/OBJECTGUID1[1]','varchar(max)')
```

Comment: Metadata was a string and that query worked!  Thank you so much!

Comment: @jtcarrie Happy to help